# SQL: Update row if the value matches one of the provided list value case insensitively

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a single column like this:

```
fruit
------
appLe
applE
cheRry
Cherry
```

and the list provided is `["aPple", "chErry"]`.

Is it possible to run a single SQL query to update this table to be like this?

```
fruit
------
aPple
aPple
chErry
chErry
```

Basically if the row matches a value of `["aPple", "chErry"]` (case insensitively), replace it with that value.

The key constraint here (what blocks me) is using a single query, so I can't do

```
update my_table set fruit = 'aPple' where UPPER(fruit) = UPPER('aPple')
update my_table set fruit = 'chErry' where UPPER(fruit) = UPPER('chErry')
```

which will be 2 queries.

Comment: When you say "the list provided", what do you mean? In any case, as Gordon points out, it's probably a very simple fix (possibly with a join to whatever list you're referring to).

Comment: Sry, I will upate the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want this:

```
UPDATE my_table
SET fruit = CASE WHEN fruit = 'apple' THEN 'aPple'
                 WHEN fruit = 'cherry' THEN 'chErry'
            END
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has case-insensitive comparisons by default.  Have you tried?

```
update t
    set fruit = 'aPple'
    where fruit = 'aPple';
```

Comment: Sry, I will updated the question, it's not very clear

Answer (score 0):

Use a case statement in the update:

```
UPDATE my_table 
    SET fruit = CASE 
      WHEN UPPER(fruit) = UPPER('aPple') THEN 'aPple' 
      WHEN UPPER(fruit) = UPPER('chErry')  THEN 'chErry'
    END
```